# Why is $this->argument() Showing the Name and the Value?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, I am making a console command. [Per the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan), you should be able to get the value of the argument using `$this->argument()`:

```
    $userId = $this->argument('user');
```

I have an argument that is an integer `1`. However, `$this->argument('some_name')` is returning a string such as `some_name=1`, instead of simply `1`

Is there a setting or something that I missed?

Comment: How are you calling the command? I'm thinking you're using it like an option instead of an argument. An argument doesn't need the argument name, where an option does. I.e. arument `php artisan somecommand 1` vs option `php artisan somecommand --some_name=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Arguments don't get named, unlike options.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments) For example:

```
$ php artisan command argument1 argument2 argument3
$ php artisan command --option1=foo --option2=bar
```

---

So, I'd either change the definition of your argument to an option so that you can run:

```
$ php artisan command --some_name=1
```

Or, you can keep using this as an argument and run:

```
$ php artisan command 1
```

---

<sub>***Note:*** *`artisan` and `command` in the above examples are arguments of the `php` executable.*</sub>